# Let $a_1=0$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3\cdots a_n$ be real numbers such that $\left|a_i\right|=\left|a_{i-1}+1\right|$ $\forall i$, then find following

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_1=0$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3\cdots a_n$ be real numbers such that $\left|a_i\right|=\left|a_{i-1}+1\right|$ $\forall i$, then the A.M. of the numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3\cdots\cdots a_n$ has the value $A$ where:

$A)$ $A<-\dfrac{1}{2}$ , $B)$ $A<-1$, $C)$ $A\ge-\dfrac{1}{2}$, $D)$ $A=-2$

My attempt is as follows:-

**Case $1$:** Let's aim for finding maximum value of $A$

$$\left|a_2\right|=|0+1|$$

As we are trying to find max value of A, so $a_2=1$

So in the same way $a_3=2,a_4=3\cdots\cdots a_n=n-1$

Hence $A_{max}=\dfrac{0+1+2+3\cdots\cdots n-1}{n}=\dfrac{n-1}{2}=\dfrac{n}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}$

As $\dfrac{n}{2}$ will be positive so $A_{max}>-\dfrac{1}{2}\tag{1}$

**Case $2$:** Let's aim for finding minimum value of $A$

$$\left|a_2\right|=|0+1|$$

As we are trying to find max value of A, so $a_2=-1$

So in the same way $a_3=0,a_4=-1\cdots\cdots$

Hence $A_{min}=\dfrac{0-1+0-1+\cdots\cdots}{n}$, $A_{min}\le-\dfrac{1}{2}$

But none of the options are matching my calculation, so how to go about this?

Actual answer is $C)  A\ge-\dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: How did you conclude that $A_{min}=\dfrac{0-1+0-1+\cdots\cdots}{n}$, $A_{min}\le-\dfrac{1}{2}$? You have either $$n=2k \Rightarrow A_{min}=-\frac{k}{2k}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ or $$n=2k+1 \Rightarrow A_{min}=-\frac{k}{2k+1}>-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: actually I forgot minus sign , thanks for noticing that.